# Create OpenFileDialog when RichTextBox selected?

Tags: vb.net, winforms, dialog

In my application, a list of fields is read from a database, and then rendered in a TabControlPage. Each field has a Control of a specific type, one of which is a RichTextBox.

What I need, is when the user selects the RichTextBox, an OpenFileDialog should appear, allowing the user to select a file. The RichTextBox should then display the full path + filename(eg. C:/files/excel/thing.xlsx) in the form of a hyperlink.

Currently, you can type in the path+filename into the RichTextBox and it will automatically be made into a hyperlink.

Any suggestions, or perhaps reference material you can give me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can attach something like this to the Enter event on your RichTextBox:

```
Dim dialog As New OpenFileDialog()
Dim result As DialogResult = dialog.ShowDialog()
If result = Windows.Forms.DialogResult.OK Then
    RichTextBox1.Text = dialog.FileName
End If
```

This is not turning it into a hyperlink for me, but it sounds like you have that part handled?

edited as per Lars' comment.

Comment: ShowDialog returns a DialogResult, not a Boolean.

Comment: That's not what it says here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-GB/library/system.windows.window.showdialog.aspx?cs-save-lang=1&cs-lang=vb#code-snippet-1

And it's working fine for me.

Comment: That's for WPF.  Post was tagged WinForms.  See [DialogResult Enumeration](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.dialogresult(v=vs.110).aspx)

Comment: Haha, fair point. Strangely though the code still seems to be compiling and working for me in a Winforms app.

Comment: Pressing the Cancel button on the dialog will also return "true" in your original version, since Cancel's value is > 0, or "not false".  :-)

Comment: Ok I got it to work, using something similar to what you have.  This seems to break my hyperlinks, but I wrote a module to just navigate to the address of the text, using either iexplore or explorer.  Thanks for your help!